# Adding search bar over MapBox layer iOS

Tags: swift, mapbox

I'm trying to add a search bar to a navigation map for MapBox on iOS, but having some trouble. I'm trying to do it programmatically in this case, as I don't have a great handle on storyboard. I've tried messing around with the zIndex as well, but still no search bar shows up for me.

Here's the code I've got so far:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UISearchBarDelegate, MGLMapViewDelegate {
    var mapView: NavigationMapView!
    lazy var directions: DirectionsManager = DirectionsManager()
    var searchBar: UISearchBar!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Setup mapbox
        let styleURL = URL(string: "style")
        mapView = NavigationMapView(frame: view.bounds, styleURL: styleURL)

        view.addSubview(mapView)
        mapView.delegate = self
        mapView.showsUserLocation = true
        mapView.setUserTrackingMode(.follow, animated: true)


        mapView.localizeLabels()

        self.searchBar = UISearchBar()
        mapView.addSubview(searchBar)
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

**@erikpartridge**, It's not an issue with mapbox, you need to set frame for UISearchBar like the below,

```
    self.searchBar = UISearchBar(frame: CGRect(x: 15, y: 50, width: (view.bounds.width-30), height: 50))
    mapView.addSubview(searchBar)
```